# Why is my negative lookbehind not working in regex?

Tags: regex

Here's my regex:

```
\w*\d{6,}\.*\-*\d|[a-z]{2}\-{1}[0-9]+\-\d*
```

And here's my haystack

> +19185555555: This is Scott with whatever company in Tulsa OK. We need a Spanish translator for an 11:00 meeting at the whereever building on Friday, 1/25/19. 444 S whatever Ave, Tulsa. The family name is Mcdowel. The contact is Katherine Zeta Jones  918-555-5555. Referral #1973756 11:28 AM

I made the regex so it wouldn't capture phone numbers but  I'm finding these pesky numbers that don't have any spaces or dashes. Luckily they can be identified in my cases because they are preceded by a "+".

I just wanted to match the referral number but it's been matching both, and outputting the first match.

I've tried a negative look behind but it isn't working on any regex tester. what's wrong with my negative look behind?

```
(?<!\+)\w*\d{6,}\.*\-*\d|[a-z]{2}\-{1}[0-9]+\-\d*
```

Comment: If you want to find the only the numbers which are preceded by a `#`, why don't you use [`(?<=#)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/SIitqz/1)?

Comment: What are you using? Python, JavaScript...?

Comment: Or perhaps `#\d{6,}\.*\-*\d|[a-z]{2}\-[0-9]+\-\d*` https://regex101.com/r/TDErGo/1

Comment: I'm using autohotkey, old version on windows xp. The fourth bird, that one worked! Thanks! I'm going to have to look yours over and see how it breaks down since it looks like you didn't even bother with lookarounds.

Comment: OK actually that one worked but only because you put the # sign in the regex, and the problem is in other instances there could be no sign in front at all. The only case I want to ignore it is if it starts with a plus sign. But I am thinking for now I might try to ignore the two area codes most common because my reference numbers will not start with those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `\d` to the character set in your negative lookbehind to avoid matching numbers following the number that follows a `+` sign:

```
(?<![+\d])\w*\d{6,}\.*\-*\d|[a-z]{2}\-{1}[0-9]+\-\d*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8Kwqys/1

Comment: Another approach would be using a word boundary `(?<!\+)\b`

Comment: Well it definitely seems to be working on regex101, but on the other regex testers I was using, it wasn't working. I'm not sure if this is just because it's not a newer engine. The site I was using was this one https://www.regextester.com/99459- is the engine just older? The program I'm running this in is autohotkey on windows xp, so it isn't new either.

Comment: After some more testing I can see that this does in fact work. I think some ancient regex testers I had been using did not have the negative lookbehind feature. In any case the \d was the part I was missing. Thank you!